# convert array of objects into simple array nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am creating project using nodejs. I want to convert array of objects into simple array.For example

```
var test =    [ { id: '1111',
        type: 'sdfsdf'
        },
      { id: 'df45',
        type: 'fsdsdf',
    }]
```

I need

```
var actual = [111,'sdfsdf'], ['df45','fsdsdf'].
```

Comment: Just use `Array#map`...

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: `test.map((el) => ([el.id, el.type]))`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Rayon: looks you love parentheses, here a bit more for you )))

Comment: @georg — It is just a habit.. ))) :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose this solution based on a dynamic number of keys:

```
var arr = test.map(function(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj). // convert object to array of keys
         reduce(function(arr, current){arr.push(obj[current]); return arr}, []); // generate a new array based on object values 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Array.map() as follows:

```
var actual = []

test.map(function(object) {
    actual.push(objectToArray(object))
})

function objectToArray(obj) {
    var array = []

    // As georg suggested, this gets a list of the keys
    // of the object and sorts them, and adds them to an array
    var obj_keys = Object.keys(obj).sort()


    // here we iterate over the list of keys
    // and add the corresponding properties from the object
    // to the 'array' that will be returned        
    for(var i = 0; i < obj_keys.length; i++) {
        array.push(obj[obj_keys[i]])
    }
    return array
}
```

The function `objectToArray` takes any object and turns it into an array so that it can be flexible regardless of the keys within the object.

Comment: I'd use `Object.keys(...).sort()` or something like this just in case.

Comment: @georg Object.keys() is cleaner, yes, you're right :) But why the sort() part? I don't get that

Comment: Imagine `{id:xxx, type:foo}, {type:bar,id:zzz}`. So either `sort`, or even better, save `.keys` of the first object and iterate that.

Comment: @Karan item here is a property of the object. More about ```for...in``` loops: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @georg That makes sense. Although we have to confirm that all objects' contents are exactly the same with Karan

Comment: This solution is correct like the accepted one, although the accepted one is more elegant, so I don't really understand the reason for the down vote.